# How to translate GDAL Terminal code for python use

Tags: python, gdalwarp

I am trying to align two raster image with each other using Gdalwarp.The code below  is Gdalwarp code.

```
gdalwarp  -tap -t_srs epsg:32614 F:\\1.tif F:\\out1.tif
gdalwarp  -tap -t_srs epsg:32614 F:\\2.tif F:\\out2.tif
```

I translate this code for python use

```
from osgeo import gdal

input_file = gdal.Open('F:\\2.tif')
ds = gdal.Warp('F:\\output2.tif', input_file, dstSRS='EPSG:32614',targetAlignedPixels= True)
ds = None
```

This code runs but is not giving me output

Comment: what is your syntax error?

Comment: when i use the code above i get syntax error.

Comment: What role Python plays?

Comment: I am using this code in jupyter notebook

Comment: what did you expect your code to do? you do nothing with `ds`